# How to set MaxLengthAttribute for IEnumerable which is returned from method (for generate swagger maxItems attribute)

Tags: c#, swagger, openapi, swashbuckle

I have a controller method that returns an array:

```
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
[Produces("application/json")]
public class WeatherForecastController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    //[MaxLength(10)]   // <- !!!!!!!!!!!!!!
    public  IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> Get([FromQuery] WeatherForecastQuery query)
...
```

a swagger spec has been generated for this controller which describes an array of responses without min/maxItems attributes

```
  ...
  "responses": {
      "200": {
        "description": "Success",
        "content": {
          "application/json": {
            "schema": {
              "type": "array",
              "items": {
                "$ref": "#/components/schemas/WeatherForecast"
              },
              //minItems: 1,   // <- I want it
              //maxItems: 10,  // <- I want it
            }}}}}
  ...
```

How can I add min/maxItems attributes to the method return array?

Answer (score 3):

MaxLengthAttribute is not a method allowed attribute,

the targets of it are

```
[System.AttributeUsage(System.AttributeTargets.Field | System.AttributeTargets.Parameter | System.AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple=false)]
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.maxlengthattribute?view=netcore-3.1

See also :

https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/issues/1747

Comment: does not look promising ((((

Comment: Most damningly, it doesn't have `AttributeTargets.ReturnValue`, which is the one that interests us.

Answer (score 0):

You have to Put the Data Annotation `[MaxLength(10)]` to your `WeatherForecastQuery` object. I think this object contains the IEnumerable?

**UPDATE**

If i now understand correctly you want to return a maximum of 10 entries.

You could return a new object like this

```
public class GetWeatherForecastResponse {
     [MaxLength(10)]
     public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> Result { get; set; }
}
```

then your controller should look like this

```
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
[Produces("application/json")]
public class WeatherForecastController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    public GetWeatherForecastResponse Get([FromQuery] WeatherForecastQuery query)
...
```

Comment: IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> is IEnumerable  (metod return).
WeatherForecastQuery is a simple class without IEnumerable.

Comment: So, changing the type of the returned object. But that's a breaking change for clients!